Confusion about Double Fourier Series of a Function
function $f$ which is periodic with respect to both $x$ and $y$ is defined on a rectangular region $[a,-a]\times[b,-b]$as $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ with period $a=b=\pi$, find double fourier series corresponding $f$.
The function $f$ is even with respect to both $x$ and $y$ and this will help simplify the process of finding the Fourier coefficients because the resulting Fourier series must have a cosine form:
$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{nm}\cos\frac{n\pi x}{a}\cos\frac{m\pi y}{b}
$$
and
$$
 a_{nm}=\frac{4}{ab}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{b}f(x,y)\cos\frac{n\pi x}{a}\cos\frac{m\pi y}{b}\,\,dxdy
$$
By substituting our function and values of $a,b$ and using linearity:
$$
 a_{nm}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(x^2+y^2) \cos(nx) \cos(my) \,\,dxdy\\ \\
 =\frac{4}{\pi^2}\bigg[\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x^2\cos(nx) \cos(my)\,\,dxdy+\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}y^2\cos(nx) \cos(my) \,\,dxdy \bigg]=0
$$
which results in double fourier series of $f$ being zero despite the fact that its piecewise continuous and periodic.
Why is this happening, I think I made a mistake but can't see where and how.
I'll be thankful if someone could help me.

Check your integration, for example the case $m = n = 0$.

The general form of double Fourier series, if the function $f$ is even with respect to both variables, is in the form:
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{a_{00}}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{0m}\cos(\frac{m\pi y}{b})+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n0}\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a})\\ +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{nm} \cos(\frac{n\pi x}{a}) \cos(\frac{m\pi y}{b})
$$
the form I stated previously in my question is wrong and in order to find the Fourier series for $f(x,y)$ we must use the formula for $a_{nm}$ and find the other 3 coefficients:
$$
\begin{gather}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle a_{nm} =\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} (x^2+y^2) \cos (my)\cos (n x)\,dydx=0 \\ \\
\displaystyle a_{00} =\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} (x^2+y^2) \,dydx=\frac{8\pi^2}{3} \\ \\
\displaystyle a_{0m}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} (x^2+y^2) \cos (my)\,dydx=\frac{8(-1)^m}{m^2} \\ \\
\displaystyle a_{n0}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} (x^2+y^2)\cos (n x)\,dydx=\frac{8(-1)^n}{n^2}
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
$$
and therefore the double Fourier series of the function $f$ will be:
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{2\pi^2}{3}+4\bigg[\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos(my)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\cos(nx)\bigg]
$$
